# Linkear dos servidores POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, linkedserver

Actualmente tengo dos bases de datos en postgres pero en diferente servidor y necesito linkearlos como se hace en SQL server, he intentado con las IP publicas es decir:

```
select * from 10.10.10.11.public.products
```

Pero hasta el momento no me lo permite...

> **NOTA:** Una de las bases de datos esta sobre *Windows*, y la otra sobre *Linux *

¿Alguna guía o orientación que me puedan brindar?

Comment: En SQL server, tú haces eso usando linked servers; no se _linkean_ (enlazan!!) con sólo hacer la consulta que indicas (ese es el resultado de crear el linked server). Busca el equivalente a eso en PGSQL. 9.3 es un poco viejo y fdw_postgres para esa versión no es muy fiable, pero debes buscar cómo montar `foreign tables`

Comment: Entiendo. lo intentare

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el módulo [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/dblink.html), que sirve para conectar bases de datos PostgreSQL. Por otro lado, y como ya te han puesto, puedes utilizar [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/postgres-fdw.html) que ofrece la misma funcionalidad con una infraestructura más moderna y pegada a estándares; sin embargo, no es soportada oficialmente en PostgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, bastante util